# How to handle this multiple delete functionality with check and uncheck code into codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below is a php code i made in a non codeigniter code work. It is a check all and uncheck all delete function. i’m not sure where to put this if it’s in the control model or view? can anyone please help me.

```
<?php

/*Check Box Commands*/
$id=$row_notification['user_id'];

if(isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
mysql_select_db($database_connection_ched, $connection_ched);
$id=$row_notification['user_id'];

for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
  {
$delete = "DELETE FROM tb_user WHERE user_id=$checkbox[$i]";
mysql_query($delete,$connection_ched);

}
$result2 = mysql_query($delete);

if($result2)
{
echo "[removed]alert ('Successfully Deleted');[removed]"; 
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=notification.php?\">"; }

}
?>
```

Comment: this question is more about the MVC paradigm than codeigniter specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using "meta refresh" for redirection.

Use PHP's header function:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You should put that code in your Controller.

Example:

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        /*Check Box Commands*/
        $id=$row_notification['user_id'];

        if(isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
        $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

        // use CodeIgniter models when communicating with your database
        // and when manipulating any database data
        // more on: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html
        mysql_select_db($database_connection_ched, $connection_ched);
        $id=$row_notification['user_id'];

        for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++) {
            $delete = "DELETE FROM tb_user WHERE user_id=$checkbox[$i]";
            mysql_query($delete,$connection_ched);
        }

        $result2 = mysql_query($delete);

        if($result2) {
            // as I pointed out, don't use "meta refresh" for redirection
            // and dont use alert for notifying anyone-anywhere
            echo "[removed]alert ('Successfully Deleted');[removed]";
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=notification.php?\">"; }
        }
    }
}
```

And small piece of advice:

**You do not have to notify anyone via JavaScript's alert function when something is deleted, inserted, altered or anything alike. Alert is a bit anoying.**

Also, checkout these links:

- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/models.html
- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/views.html
- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/controllers.html

That should help you get a more clearer picture how MVC works, and how CodeIgniter works.

Comment: so the db query should be put in model? and everything else from this code will be in the control?

Comment: Not excatly. You should read more how MVC works excatly, and how just should start avoing mysql_* functions because they are slowly being removed out of usage.

Comment: if my question was helpful, please vote it up, thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Why your result should be on javascript and refreshing? This is wrong you need it. Script will be execute once, not refreshing. You need only print result.

Use

```
   if ($result2 === true)  { echo 'Result: deleted '; }
```

instead of:

```
echo "[removed]alert ('Successfully Deleted');[removed]"; 
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=notification.php?\">"; }
```

Check it with `var_dump()` inside for loop, maybe is not receiving a data.

Or try repair your code better:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
  {
    $delete = "DELETE FROM tb_user WHERE user_id={$checkbox[$i]}";
    mysql_query($delete,$connection_ched);

}
```